# c : matrix multiplication without * operator

Tags: c, matrix

I have to write a c program which multiplies two matrices without using the * operator. I wrote a code but the result is not correct I think something with the while loop is not correct. I hope someone can help. greetings M

Here is my code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int matrix1[4][4];
  int matrix2[4][4];
  int matrix3[4][4];
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int sum;
  int multi = 0;

  //first matrix
  for(a=0; a<4; a++)
  {
    for(b=0; b<4; b++)
    {
      scanf("%d", &matrix1[a][b]);
    }
  }
  //second matrix
  for(a=0; a<4; a++)
  {
    for(b=0; b<4; b++)
    {
      scanf("%d", &matrix2[a][b]);
    }
  }
//Multiplication:
  for(a=0; a<=3; a++)
  {
    for(b=0; b<=3; b++)
    {
      sum=0;
      for(c=0; c<=3; c++)
      {
        while(matrix2[c][b]>0)
        {
          multi += matrix1[a][c];
          matrix2[c][b]--;
        }
      }
      sum = sum+multi;
      matrix3[a][b]=sum;
    }
  }

  //result;
  for(a=0; a<4; a++)
  {
    for(b=0; b<4; b++)
    {
      printf(" %d ", matrix3[a][b]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about the definition of multiplication.

Comment: "I think" sounds like you need to learn how to use a debugger. Knowing how to debug a program is very handy, and part of the skill.

Comment: the `*` operator as in the arithmetic operator, or `*` as in: pointer/dereferencing operator?

Comment: as in the arithmetic operator

Comment: Using `matrix2[c][b]--;` you are modifying the value in matrix, so next time that value will be 0...

Comment: Divide the program into functional units and test them separately. You can't use `*`? Then write a function`mul(a,b)` and use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 main errors

1. You must reset `multi` to `0` not `sum`, that is useless
2. You must use a temp variable for your moltiplication,. Your code modify the original value of matrix using `matrix2[c][b]--;`

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int matrix1[4][4] = { {1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
    int matrix2[4][4] = { {17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24},{25,26,27,28},{29,30,31,32}};
    int matrix3[4][4];
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int multi = 0;

    //Multiplication:
    for (a = 0; a < 4; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b < 4; b++)
        {
            multi = 0;
            for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                int temp = matrix2[c][b];
                while (temp > 0)
                {
                    multi += matrix1[a][c];
                    temp--;
                }
            }
            matrix3[a][b] = multi;
        }
    }

    //result;
    for (a = 0; a < 4; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b < 4; b++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", matrix3[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
250  260  270  280  
618  644  670  696  
986  1028 1070 1112 
1354 1412 1470 1528
```